# Array1 consist of numbers divisible by 3. Make an array2 where the first elements are odd, then even

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

```
int main() {
    int tab1[20], tab2[20], a, b, i, x;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        x=rand()%(b+1-a)+a;
        while(x%3!=0){
            x=rand()%(b+1-a)+a;
        }
        tab1[i]=x;
        if(tab1[i]%2!=0){
            tab2[i]=tab1[i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        printf("%d ", tab1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        printf("%d ", tab2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The full task is: Make an array consisting of 20 elements builded of random numbers divisible by 3 in a given range (a,b). Make a second array builded as first elements are odd, then even.
Sorry if this makes little to no sense, I translated it from Polish.

This is what I came up with, which doesn't work because if `tab1[i]%2==0` then it generates junk. I don't know how to get around it without using complex sorting functions. We had 15 min to do this, and if possible with only one for loop.

This is what it should look like given array1[3]:
{3,6,6,3}
then array2 should look like:
{3,3,6,6}
Hope you understand now.

Comment: `tab1[i]%==0` is a mystery to me. Among other reasons because I do not see it in the code.

Comment: Where is your problem? Where you seem to attempt to generate an array full of random numbers in a given range which are also divisible by 3? (That does not seem to be the actual goal described in the title.) Or with actually sorting the arrray? Please focus on what you need help with.

Comment: The problem is incompletely specified.  Is it *the program* that is responsible for generating Array1?  Are the elements of `array2` supposed to be the same as `array1`, reordered?  Does "odd then even" mean all the odd elements followed by all the even elements, or does it mean alternating between odd and even?  Is the array size specified as part of the problem, or did you just invent that?  Is the output that matters, or the data structures appearing in the program source?

Comment: About the `while` loop: if you want a random number divisible by 3, pick a random number and multiply it by 3.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, it's my first question here. I already edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

I would just change this part and initialized variables, you don't need so much.

```
        if(tab1[i]%2!=0){
            tab2[i]=tab1[i];
        }
```

So except that, you want to have one variable, which tells you how many odd numbers you've already got. Let's call it `oddsCount`.
Each time you'll have odd number you'll increment it.

Also in i-th step you'll have `i-oddsCount` even numbers.

So let's put it into code

```
if(tab1[i]%2!=0){
   tab2[oddsCount]=tab1[i];
   ++oddsCount;
} else {
// 19 is last index of the array size
   tab2[19-(i-oddsCount)] = tab1[i]
}
```

Comment: Key to understanding this approach is that even numbers are added to `tab2` from back to front, and odds from front to back.  You don't then need to know in advance how many of each there will be, and you don't need to move any elements after first writing them.